# What is the longest time after which plane crash survivors were rescued?

Tags: aviation-history, accidents, accident-statistics

I found:

- Aviator [Bob Gauchie](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/pilot-bob-gauchies-story-of-how-he-survived-nearly-two-months-in-brutally-cold-wilderness-before-his-rescue) retains the record for solo arctic survival by a downed airman, enduring **58 days** of arctic weather before his rescue in Canada 1967.
- After **72 days** on the glacier, 16 of the 45 people on board the crashed [Uruguayan Air Force Flight 571](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruguayan_Air_Force_Flight_571) were rescued alive.

Any longer ?

---

*scope: For the purpose of this question only the initial rescue from the crash site shall be considered.*

Comment: Francis Gary Powers survived in a [Russian prison after his plane was shot down, for 1 year 9 months and 10 days before being rescued](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Gary_Powers) if that counts...

Comment: thanks. I clarified the scope.

Comment: The #1 and #2 records in this category are held by Tom Hanks and Wilson. :)

Comment: At what point can we consider people are rescued? when they are spotted by rescue teams? when they are in the vehicle bringing them to an hospital? when they have been examined and doctors say "they will live"? when they leave the medical facility after intense medical treatment?

Comment: @ManuH - I'd assume when they are physically picked up by rescue teams/walk themselves to safety

Comment: @ManuH, if you find an example that breaks down the timeline in such detail please don't hesitate to post it due to concerns over when the stopwatch was clicked.

Answer (score 6):

I have not found a period longer than the two you provided (quoted for completeness). It is unlikely that there is a longer period unreported, as that would be a major news item or historical note; it is possible but unverifiable there has been a person survive after a crash longer but was never rescued due to the aircraft [never being recovered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_missing_aircraft).

> - Aviator [Bob Gauchie](https://nationalpost.com/news/canada/pilot-bob-gauchies-story-of-how-he-survived-nearly-two-months-in-brutally-cold-wilderness-before-his-rescue) retains the record for solo arctic survival by a downed airman, enduring **58 days** of arctic weather before his rescue in Canada 1967.
> - After **72 days** on the glacier, 16 of the 45 people on board the crashed [Uruguayan Air Force Flight 571](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uruguayan_Air_Force_Flight_571) were rescued alive.

A couple notable contenders and interesting anecdotes:

- [Howard Snyder](https://www.capjournal.com/news/wwii-pilot-howard-snyder-s-tale-of-being-shot-down/article_4f0411e6-c83a-11e7-a9ab-e3f0d7e491c3.html) was shot down over Belgium during WWII and joined the Belgium resistance, staying with them for **over 6 months** until he was rescued by US Troops
- [Louis Zamperini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Zamperini)'s **47 days** on the ocean after his B-24 crashed in the Pacific during WWII, likely an oceanic survival record after a plane crash, was depicted in the film and book *Unbroken*. Zamperini then spent another 28 months in Japanese prison camps before being repatriated
- [Roger Locher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Locher) holds the USAF evasion record behind enemy lines, spending **23 days** evading North Vietnamese troops during the Vietnam war after his F-4 was shot down
- [Juliane Koepecke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juliane_Koepcke)'s **11 days** in the Peruvian jungle after falling from a disintegrating airplane
- The record for desert survival, albeit with an unfortunate lack of rescue, the [crew of *Lady Be Good*](https://www.airforcemag.com/PDF/MagazineArchive/Documents/2014/February%202014/0214lady.pdf) (WWII)

  > They survived for **over a week** in the desert with essentially no water, covering 115 miles...The remains of Moore are still lost in the Sahara’s Sand Sea of Calanscio. But he clearly broke all records for stamina and desert survival

Comment: Of the crew of the _Lady Be Good_, "They died trying". The best epitaph any of us could ask for.

Answer (score -3):

There was a case in New Jersey in 1996 where a High school soccer team crashed in the Canadian wilderness and were presumed dead untill they were rescued 19 months later

Comment: Is this the fictional series 'yellow jackets'? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellowjackets_(TV_series) ?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation Stack Exchange!  While we thank you for your answer, it would be greatly improved if it include supporting references.  Please [edit] so that your answer can be confirmed.